# Lost the scope of of a function inside a object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, I'm losing reference to a property of an object ana when it runs within an event `$(window).resize`

As I can do to keep the scope.

Example:

```
var testObject = {

        init: function () {
            this.divOriginal = $('.selector-tag');            
            this.resizeNow();
        },

        resizeNow: function () {
            //some another code here....
            //....
            //..
            $(window).resize(this.resizeUpdate.bind(this)); //without bind(this) the scope is window            
        },

        resizeUpdate: function() {
            console.log($(this));
            var scrollWrapper = $(this)[0].divOriginal;//the only way to refer to the divOriginal 
            scrollWrapper.css('border','1px solid red');
        }
}

testObject.init();
```

There is a cleaner way to access the object's attributes?

Comment: Please explain exactly what code is losing reference to a property and show us how that code is called.  The value of `this` in a function is determined by how the function is called.  So, we have to know exactly where you are losing that and how it is being called so we can make the right specific suggestions for how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the object using `this` instead of `$(this)` since you bound your object to the method called by the event handler.

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on Function.prototype.bind() :

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   **this** keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: That should go in comments :)

Comment: you are right, sometimes the simplest is what we least expect. You do not know how long with this pass, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with more explanations.